# Python Click determine order of chained commands before execution

Tags: python, command-line-interface, python-click

I write a CLI application using Click. I have a group that allows to chain commands, application is called like `my_cli cmd1 --arg1 val1 cmd2 run`. I want to ensure that the `run` command is specified by the user at the very end and not in the middle. Can this be achieved with click? Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You can actually just bypass Click entirely for this, and just check if a `run` command is is any position other than last:

```
from sys import argv

def check_run_command_pos():
    if "run" in argv[:-1]:
    raise SyntaxError('`run` must be the last command of a chain')

if __name__ == "__main__":
    check_run_command_pos()
```

Comment: There are lots of commands with arguments etc., they are also dynamically loaded, so bypassing click is not an option

Comment: If you have more requirements than in your original question, please submit a [minimum verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) of your code so that others can help you more efficiently.

Comment: Ahh, okay, I see your point. That might work, but requires lots of manual parsing. So an alternative solution would be great.

Answer (score 0):

If we're staying within Click, the best thing I can think of is to compose your command chain using the `@click.group()` decorator, then evaluate the chain using the `resultcallback()` decorator:

```
import click

@click.group(chain=True)
def cli():
    """Example script that checks its input arg order."""
    pass

@cli.command('action1')
def action1():
    return 'action1'

@cli.command('action2')
def action2():
    return 'action2'

@cli.command('run')
def run():
    return 'run'

@cli.resultcallback()
def check_run_pos(actions):
    if 'run' in actions[:-1]:
        raise SyntaxError("`run` must be the last command in a pipeline")
    else:
        print(actions)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    cli()
```

Now we get:

```
$ app.py action1 action2 action1 run
['action1', 'action2', 'action1', 'run']

$ app.py action1 run action2 run
SyntaxError: `run` must be the last command in a pipeline
```

This is easier to extend and avoids manual parsing, as with each `run` command, you get the ability to evaluate the full chain of actions leading up to it and determine programmatically whether or not it's kosher to use the `run` action at any given time.

Comment: But this has the problem that `resultcallback()` is not invoked until the *after* the commands have been run.

Comment: Yeah, `run` command actually starts computing pipeline, while all previous commands determine what files this pipeline should generate, so this is not an option

Answer (score -1):

Please check the [Nested Commands](https://click.palletsprojects.com/en/7.x/quickstart/#nesting-commands) docs. I believe that's what you are looking for. You can add `run` as a last nested command so it will not be able to execute somewhere else.

> **Nesting Commands**
>
> Commands can be attached to other commands of type Group. This allows arbitrary nesting of scripts. As an example here is a script that implements two commands for managing databases
>
> ...

Comment: That doesn't matter, they can be called in an arbitrary order.